# Cartesian Join on a Seq against itself?

Tags: scala

Given

```
val numbers = Seq(1,2,3)
numbers.combinations(2).toList
```

gives

```
res2: List[Seq[Int]] = List(List(1, 2), List(1, 3), List(2, 3))
```

Instead of getting the pairwise combination, what is the name of the function for getting ordered? combinations.

e.g.

List(`1,2` `1,3`
`2,1` `2,3`
`3,1` `3,2`)

Comment: Do you want (1,1), (2,2) etc to be part of the combinations?

Comment: 1,1 No, I don't want it to match with itself, however the order matters. so (1,2) is not the same as (2,1) so both should be listed. I know the terms I've used arn't correct, but I don't know the correct name. I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will result in all the expected pairs, but not in the order you've requested.

```
numbers.combinations(2).flatMap(p => List(p,p.reverse)).toList
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the simple ways is to use for loop as

```
scala> val numbers = Seq(1,2,3)
//numbers: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> for(num1 <- numbers; num2 <- numbers; if(num1 != num2)) yield (num1, num2)
//res0: Seq[(Int, Int)] = List((1,2), (1,3), (2,1), (2,3), (3,1), (3,2))
```

Another way is to use permutation as

```
scala> val numbers = Seq(1,2,3)
//numbers: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> numbers.permutations.map(list => (list(0), list(1))).toSet.toList
//res0: List[(Int, Int)] = List((3,1), (3,2), (1,3), (2,3), (1,2), (2,1))
```

Comment: @RyanTheLeach I have updated my answer please have a look